# Flagged a programming question but it was declined

Tags: discussion

[Using PHP inside .html files not working as expected](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87122/using-php-inside-html-files-not-working-as-expected)

I thought programming questions should be moved to stackoverflow so I flagged it and it was declined. Specifically, the FAQ states javascript questions are off topic and PHP is, essentially, in the same realm. You can't even ask about CMSes which are often programmed with PHP.

So why was it declined?

Answer (score 2):

That question isn't a coding question.   It is a server configuration question.   It would be off-topic for StackOverflow.   If it were to be moved to another site, it would be most appropriate for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

The reasons to move a question are:

- It is off-topic here.
- The community is more likely to be able to answer the question on another site.

The second reason is why programming questions are more appropriate for StackOverflow.   Some of the people who answer questions here are coders, but everybody at StackOverflow is a coder.

The question now has several answers and it seems appropriate for this site to me, so it can stay.

Comment: I must have skipped over the first few lines of his question and only read the part about getting his PHP to work inside his HTML, or it was edited in a way that I missed it, but I certainly don't recall the question looking like that when I first read it. So I'll just label it an oopsy.

Comment: @Rob It is not uncommon that a question is edited in a way that changes the whole nature of the question. I too have flagged questions before only to have them edited and the flag declined. I just happens that way sometimes. I too have also missed a critical part of a question or failed to understand it fully. That happens too. We are all humans... or at least some of us are... ;-) ...and we all make mistakes. I would not lose any sleep over it. Cheers!!